# Batch File, get each word of variable and set for each arguments

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Basicily everything is in the title.

```bash
:console_exec
set /p "cmd=->"
set "console_exec=True"
goto :main
```

When I pass an input to to set /p it is reading as entire string
In :main

```bash
:main
if "%cmd%"=="say" (
    set "_string="
    goto :say
    )
```

When I do "say hi" in the set /p it is reading it as if "say hi" == "say" but i want "hi" to be the next argument passed like %~2, any help is appriecieted.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `if`, when you use the given capabilities of the language. Just try to jump to the "command" label. Redirect the errormessage (with non-existing labels). You can even give an own message then:

```
@echo off
setlocal 
:console_exec
set /p "cmd=->"
2>nul call :%cmd% || echo invalid command
goto :console_exec

:say
echo --- %1
REM echo --- %*  // for more than one word
```

Comment: This is not what i needed but i will try to change my code. Thanks!

Comment: I have a one thing that i don't understand. What is 2>nul ?

Comment: it redirects output steam 2 (STDERR, where errors usually go) to the `NUL` device ("nirvana"). Just remove it and watch the difference.